# Error: Android studio emulator has a black screen when starting up

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu8FC.png)
I have tried everything like using cold boot, wiping data but it still shows a black screen.

- Android studio version in use: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
  Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636, built on September 15, 2023
  Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 x86_64
  VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
  macOS 13.5
  GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
  Memory: 2048M
  Cores: 20
  Metal Rendering is ON
  Registry:
  external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
  ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
- Hackintosh Mac configuration:
  Processor : 2,11 GHz Intel Core Processor 12th Gen
  Graphics : AMD Radeon RX 580 8 GB
  Memory : 32 GB 3000 MHz DDR4
  MacOS Ventura ver 13.5

I want to run the emulator successfully

Comment: Have you tried hitting the power button on the emulator?

Comment: I also tried it and got no results

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all warning by changing/updating all version(compile/build etc) in build.gradle to make everything same(pointing to same version). Or just simply update everything to latest version. Mouse-Hover over the things will show you the latest version recommended.

Make sure your your app->bulid.gradle file have same verison with compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion and support libraries notice the support libraries verison which in this example 32. If I have 32.0.2 buildToolsVersion I will change my support libraries version 32 too.

Comment: The problem here is when I start the AVD and it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 32
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

Like This Try

Comment: The problem here is when I start the AVD and it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

try to press the power on button

[image]

Comment: it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just created the AVD with 768 MB RAM and it did run fine!

Enable checkbox "Enable device frame" in avd config.

Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator -> Uncheck “Launch in a tool window

you can try these above.It will might work